# Updating spring boot static resources after deploying JAR file

Tags: java, spring-boot, continuous-integration

I have developed a REST API with Spring Boot. I've used Angular for front-end and added its files to resources/static. Everything is working fine.

I currently deploy my application in fat JAR format. The spring boot application does not change very often but I have to change the front-end day by day. Is there any way to somehow inject the updated angular files to currently deployed JAR file? Or I should change the packaging to WAR and use external tomcat server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, yes, you can update an existing jar file by using the [jar command](https://medium.com/better-programming/live-reloading-with-docker-compose-for-efficient-development-356d50e91e39):

`jar uf jar-file input-file(s)`

However, you still need to **restart** the process.

I assume, your question is more about `hot deployment` or `hot swapping` - how to add new files without stopping a running process.

In the case of a spring-boot application with an embedded Tomcat in **a production environment**, you still need to restart it.

So, the easiest way to achieve a hot deploy of an angular front-end is to split your jar, extract an angular app, and deploy it separately.

As you mentioned, you can deploy a war with an angular app to a Tomcat instance. If you use a Linux based machine, I would recommend packing the angular app to a tar/zip and extracting it to an Apache httpd or nginx web server.

Also, you can use, for example, docker-compose for [live reloading](https://medium.com/better-programming/live-reloading-with-docker-compose-for-efficient-development-356d50e91e39).

In the case of **a development environment**, it's much easier, because you can make use of an IDE support combined with spring-boot-devtools to achieve hot swapping, more explained at [spring-boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html).

Comment: Splitting angular and rest server requires two separate web servers?

Comment: It depends. 

You can plan your environment as: **one Tomcat instance** to deploy your angular war and REST war. In such a case, you need to change from a jar with embedded Tomcat for REST services to a deployable war. 

But also, you can use **two servers**. For example, you can keep an embedded Tomcat in a REST jar and deploy an angular app to a different server (Tomcat or a web server).

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can define any directory as source of your static files:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
      .addResourceLocations("file:///e:/app/resources/public/")
     //other options
}}
```

No idea if it works in production, I've done some prototyping only. There is a bit more on [Baeldung page](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) (old article, but updated to Spring 5), and official [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources)